# CMD Curl equivalent in PHP - python script flask

Tags: php, curl

I'm calling a python api via my CMD.

```
@app.route("/getResult", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def funcName():
    print("Fetching  the passed input file")
    f = request.files['data']

    print("Reading the file using pandas")
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
```

This is how i call it in cmd and it returns just a number output.

```
curl -F data=@location\data_sample.csv localhost:5000/getResult
```

I'm trying to call it via php with the following code.

```
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        $postData = array(
            'data' => '@'.$file_path,
        );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($response);die();
```

I get this error:

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

> werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand. KeyError: 'data'

Answer (score 0):

As for me you send only string `@location\data_sample.csv` because command `@` probably may work only in real `curl`.

Based on PHP documentation you should use [CURLFile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php) or `curl_file_create`

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = curl_file_create('location/data_sample.csv', 'text/csv', 'data_sample.csv');

 // Assign POST data
$data = array('data' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);die();
```

---

**EDIT:**

Full code which I used to test it.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print("Fetching  the passed input file")
    f = request.files['data']

    print("Reading the file using pandas")
    data = pd.read_csv(f)
    
    print("Send back as HTML with table")
    return data.to_html()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.debug = True
    app.run() #debug=True
```

**main.php**

```
<?php

$uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/';

$file_path = 'location/data_sample.csv';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);

//$postData = array('data' => '@'.$file_path);  // doesn't work

// Create a CURLFile object
$cfile = curl_file_create($file_path, 'text/csv', 'data_sample.csv');
//$cfile = new CURLFile($file_path, 'text/csv', 'data_sample.csv');

 // Assign POST data
$postData = array('data' => $cfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($response);
die();

?>
```

Tested on `Linux Mint 20`, `PHP 7.4.3`, `Python 3.8.5`.

I had to use `/` instead of `\` in `'location/data_sample.csv'`